`BaseSettings` has been moved to the `pydantic-settings` package
I am struggling with this error from long now, tried other solutions but no luck, here is my overview about the issue.
Firstly i am not at all using this package anywhere in my project, seems like python is executing this internally, but still i am facing this issue, here are my python configurations
Python 3.9.6
pip 21.2.4

I tried other version of python too which is 3.10.9
Below is the error i am facing.
  File "/Users/pradeepyenkuwale/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/langchain/vectorstores/chroma.py", line 81, in __init__
    import chromadb
  File "/Users/pradeepyenkuwale/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/chromadb/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import chromadb.config
  File "/Users/pradeepyenkuwale/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/chromadb/config.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pydantic import BaseSettings, Field
  File "/Users/pradeepyenkuwale/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pydantic/__init__.py", line 380, in __getattr__
    return _getattr_migration(attr_name)
  File "/Users/pradeepyenkuwale/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pydantic/_migration.py", line 296, in wrapper
    raise PydanticImportError(
pydantic.errors.PydanticImportError: `BaseSettings` has been moved to the `pydantic-settings` package. See https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.7/migration/#basesettings-has-moved-to-pydantic-settings for more details.

For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.7/u/import-error

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/pradeepyenkuwale/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2213, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/pradeepyenkuwale/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2193, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/Users/pradeepyenkuwale/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 176, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "/Users/pradeepyenkuwale/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 176, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "/Users/pradeepyenkuwale/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2190, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/pradeepyenkuwale/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1486, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/pradeepyenkuwale/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 176, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "/Users/pradeepyenkuwale/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 176, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "/Users/pradeepyenkuwale/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1484, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/pradeepyenkuwale/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1469, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "/Users/pradeepyenkuwale/Work/Repositories/TripAdvisor/setup.py", line 53, in userQuery
    resp = ProcessConsumerQuery(query)
  File "/Users/pradeepyenkuwale/Work/Repositories/TripAdvisor/lib/process_query.py", line 30, in ProcessConsumerQuery
    index = VectorstoreIndexCreator().from_loaders([loader])
  File "/Users/pradeepyenkuwale/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/langchain/indexes/vectorstore.py", line 83, in from_loaders
    return self.from_documents(docs)
  File "/Users/pradeepyenkuwale/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/langchain/indexes/vectorstore.py", line 88, in from_documents
    vectorstore = self.vectorstore_cls.from_documents(
  File "/Users/pradeepyenkuwale/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/langchain/vectorstores/chroma.py", line 771, in from_documents
    return cls.from_texts(
  File "/Users/pradeepyenkuwale/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/langchain/vectorstores/chroma.py", line 707, in from_texts
    chroma_collection = cls(
  File "/Users/pradeepyenkuwale/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/langchain/vectorstores/chroma.py", line 84, in __init__
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Could not import chromadb python package. Please install it with pip install chromadb.`

FYI, I am using LangChain AI framework with ChatGPT.
The same code works fine in windows machine, i am trying to run the repository in MacBook Pro, I tried same version as in windows as well but still i am facing this issue.

Does this help py -m pip install chromadb?

@toyotaSupra, That is not the actual issue, that exception occurred due to the first one, FYI, tried installing chromadb, but no luck, i feel like, if first issue gets resolved, the second one will go automatically

Anyone any update on this please?

Can you update Python 3.12.2? It is a free bug.

@toyotaSupra is this something specific i need update to 3.12.2?
or i can use latest version which is 3.12.3?
FYI, i tried with 3.12.3, i am facing same issue.

I'm running Python 3.12.3 today and it worked right now.

Hi there, i am still facing this issue, FYI, i am using LangChain the AI Frame work with chatGPT, suggest me some inputs here, this issue is really bothering me a lot. Just for your information, the same code is working as expected in windows machine, i was trying to run the repo in MacBook Pro, and i am facing this issue.

U should have edited to ur question.

@toyotaSupra let me do it

Could you add the output of pip list for your environment? Is it identical on your Windows and MacBook environments - specifically the chromadb and pydantic versions?

@nigh_anxiety buddy you solved my anxiety bro, this did the trick, my windows chromadb version is 0.4.20 and in MAC it was 0.3.8 and windows pydantic version is 2.5.2 and MAC it was 2.7.0, I have installed windows versions of both the packages it worked without error. But, why it should be like this?, rather then giving me the version error, it gave me some other error, which caused the confusion

@PradeepYenkuwale Well, Having different versions of the packages isn't necessarily a problem by itself.  Python doesn't know what versions you should  have. However, the issue is that chromadb is dependent on pydantic, and pydantic made a breaking change a while ago by moving settings to pydantic-settings which chromadb then needed to make updates to handle. I'm not clear on exactly what versions of each are affected, but from looking at the github repo for chromadb it all of the related issues are closed as of version 4.2 or 4.3, I think.

This is why you should use pip freeze > requirements.txt to get the list of needed packages when you try moving your development to another computer.  Then in the virtual environment on the other computer (if you aren't using virtual environments, now is the time to start), you use pip install -r requirements.txt to install all of the packages needed with the same versions.

@nigh_anxiety Appreciated!!
